# tinyMCE setup callback versus onAddEditor

Tags: tinymce

When you initialize a tinyMCE editor I have noticed two different ways to get called when the editor is created.

One way is using the setup callback that is part of [tinyMCE.init](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:setup):

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      // do things with editor ed
   }
});
```

The other way is to hook up to the [onAddEditor](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.onAddEditor) event:

```
tinyMCE.onAddEditor.add(function(mgr,ed) {
    // do things with editor ed
});
```

What are the differences between using these two methods?

Is the editor in a different state in one versus the other? For example, are things not yet loaded if I try to access properties on the editor object.

What are reasons to use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference here is that `tinyMCE.onAddEditor` adds code to be executed onthe AddEditor event and fires when a new editor instance is added to the tinymce collection 
while the `setup` setting lets you add events to the editor. It gets executed before the editor instances gets rendered.

One other difference is that `setup` is to be set inside the tinymce initialization call (the configuration setting) while `onAddEditor` usually gets called inside a tinymce plugin (but you may also set it inside the setup function).

Comment: I get the differences about where you can set them up. I am trying to get at why you would use one over the other? Are there actions you can take on an editor that would only work in one of those callbacks?

Comment: i would use the setup callback if i didn't want to create an own plugin (in my case i use mode: "textareas", so i do not use addControl to initialize them)

Comment: As far as messing with inspecting the editor and messing with its dom, would using setup cause an issue since it is called earlier?

Comment: well, i don't think so. but be aware that moving an editor in the dom will throw errors unless you don'T removeControl first before you reinitialize the editor instance again using addcontrol

Answer (score 3):

onAddEditor.add gives warning in the latest TinyMCE 4:

```
Deprecated TinyMCE API call: <target>.onAddEditor.add(..)
```

`.on(nameofevent, function(){...} )` is the proper way to do this in MCE4 if you don't have the backward-compatibility plugin.